# How to do "adb logcat" via Wifi without connecting the device to the computer first?

Tags: android, adb, remote-debugging, wireless

I'm developing an app for a custom Android x86 build using a mini PC. I'm trying to debug and do the logcat on it via Wifi, since I can't really connect the mini PC to my workstation using USB and logcat it the usual way. Or at least not that I'm aware of. But on every articles and tutorials that I've read, the first step to do adb via Wifi is to connect the device first and do "adb tcpip 5555", which I cannot do, or I don't know how to do. So is there anyway to debug and log the mini PC without connecting it to the workstation first?

Thanks.

Comment: You would need to connect once atleast to allow wirelss debugging. After that you can try doing wifi. But you need to connect atleast once.

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of. Is there no other way around it? I don't see any USB output socket on the mini PC so I don't know where to plug it. Testing on a phone / tablet didn't work since the environment is very different between the mini PC and usual Android devices. It has a very lightweight custom ROM and some specific services in the background. Not to mention the peripherals like camera, COM-port analog devices, etc. To describe it further, try imagining an arcade game rig using Android.

Comment: Oh yeah BTW, I've tested the app on my Android phone and it worked flawlessly, while in the rig it didn't. And I don't even have a slight clue as to why.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but is it possible to open a SSH tunnel from the PC to the mini PC and maybe try setting up a connection this way? I'm not sure if this might work, maybe it's possible...

Comment: there is this post on how to do using bluetooth and wifi for debugging. Maybe this helps:
http://zcourts.com/2013/07/19/android-debugging-over-bluetooth-without-root/#sthash.hVCLtWSk.h1nwhsAw.dpbs

Comment: Some people mentioned that this is a duplicate. I'll try to look at the other answer. Thanks guys. Will update it afterwards.

Comment: Okay. It worked. So the answer is in the duplicate link above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Comment: Use ADB wifi connect app

Answer (score -3):

There is no way to do that in devices that are not rooted,even for rooted ones you do realize that would be a security problem right ,anyone whose debugging is enabled could be connected then.